# Is it possible to create Job Schedule using T-SQL script (not SQL Server Agent schedule creation wizard)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to create a script which will execute at scheduled times. Because my client is not familiar with SQL Server, I would like to create a schedule on my machine as per my client's requirements using SQL Server Agent schedule creation wizard, then create a script of the created schedule (which I will send to the client).

How can I create a T-SQL Job Schedule without using the SQL Server Agent schedule creation wizard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use management studio to get the creation script.

Create the job in management studio

Then right click the job and from the floating menu select Script The Job As -> Create To -> New Query Editor Window.

Alter the script details to match your needs

Answer (score 8):

To create a SQL Server Agent job using Transact-SQL:

- Execute sp_add_job to create a job.
- Execute sp_add_jobstep to create one or more job steps.
- Execute sp_add_schedule to create a schedule.
- Execute sp_attach_schedule to attach a schedule to the job.
- Execute sp_add_jobserver to set the server for the job.

More [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I see you accepted the above answer, but if you're trying to create a schedule specifically which is what your question said, as opposed to a job, you use [sp_add_schedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187320.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can start [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173757.aspx), run your wizard steps, and then see what SQL has been executed in the background, using this as a basis for preparing your scripts.

Comment: Why would you do this when SSMS or Smo will both generate a script for you?

Comment: It's a good general method for finding out what any tool is doing, and hardly rates negative votes.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the job and want to add a new schedule, and then add this to multiple jobs you could script it this way (this is an example for a frequence of 1x/day at 02h00, added to 2 jobs)

```
USE [msdb]
GO

DECLARE @schedule_id int, @job_id uniqueidentifier

-- create the schedule
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_schedule @schedule_name=N'name of the schedule', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=4, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=1, 
        @freq_subday_interval=0, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
        @active_start_date=20180703, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=020000, 
        @active_end_time=235959, @schedule_id = @schedule_id OUTPUT

-- add it to job 1
set @job_id = (select job_id from msdb.dbo.sysjobs where name='Name of job 1')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_attach_schedule @job_id=@job_id,@schedule_id= @schedule_id

-- add it to job 2
set @job_id = (select job_id from msdb.dbo.sysjobs where name='Name of job 2')
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_attach_schedule @job_id=@job_id,@schedule_id= @schedule_id

GO
```